# It’s all well and good

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I know usually well is an adverb and good is an adjective. I can clearly see in the expression

> It’s all well and good

that well is an adverb for is. Forgive my ignorance, but what is **‘good’** in this sentence? Can it also be an adverb?

Answer (score 2):

"All well and good" is usually used to state that something, while seeming to be correct or reasonable, actually has faults or disadvantages. John says "I'm very sorry that I dented  your car, but I have washed it.". I can say, "That's all well and good, but the damage will cost $100 to repair". The expression can be used sarcastically if something is greatly less than what is required or necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> It’s all *well* and *good*.

In here, *"well"* is an adjective, so is *"good"*. The adjective *"well"* is being modified by the determinative *"all"*. The adjective phrase *"all well"* is being coordinated with another adjective *"good"* by a coordinator "and".

By the way, *"(all) well and good"* is an idiomatic expression.